# How to remove partial duplicates from a table

Tags: postgresql, delete, duplication

I have a database that contains some erroneous results that are essentially but not technically duplicates. The structure is like this:

```
id_page (PK), id_site, label, create_date
```

There should only be one entry for each site for each label but it turns out that I have some duplicates for `site` and `label`, where `id_page` and `create_date` are different. I would like to remove the rows with the lowest `create_date`.

I think I have come up with a solution for this but I'd appreciate feedback.

```
WITH duplicates as (
   SELECT id_page, id_site, count(id_site) over (partition by id_site) as ct, 
    min("create_date") over (partition by id_site) as dt
   from pages
   where label = '2018-12-15'
   )
DELETE from pages
where id_page in (
   select p.id_page
   from duplicates as d
   join pages as p on (p.id_page = d.id_page
                   and p.create_date = d.dt)
WHERE ct = 2
);
```

Comment: You say `where id_page and create_date are different`. Does that mean *both* have to differ or (at least) one of both? Which columns can be NULL? Where do you consider NULL values equal? A table definition with all constraints (`CREATE TABLE ...`) would clarify. And *always* your version of Postgres.

Comment: `I would like to remove the rows with the lowest create_date.` If there can be more than one dupe, then I assume you mean: *I would like to keep one row with the highest `create_date` per set of peers.* Can there be multiple peers with the same `create_date`? If so, how to break ties?

Comment: No columns can be `NULL`. `id_page` is the PK so is always unique, `create_date` should be different. And, yes, your assumption is correct. If have `(id_site = 50, create_date=1234)` and `(id_site=50 and create_date=2345)`, I'd like to keep the second row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WITH duplicates as 
(
    SELECT id_page, id_site,
           row_number() over (partition by id_site order by id_site, create_date) rn
    FROM   pages
    WHERE  label = '2018-12-15'
)
DELETE FROM pages 
WHERE  id_page IN (SELECT id_page 
                   FROM   duplicates
                   WHERE  rn > 1);
```

Comment: Thanks, I'd seen something like this but I didn't know I could use `row_number()`. Only difference with my query is that this appears to return the `id_page` with the higher `create_date`

Answer (score 2):

For the information given, assuming all columns `NOT NULL`:

```
DELETE FROM pages p
WHERE  label = '2018-12-15'
AND    EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM page
   WHERE  label       = p.label
   AND    id_site     = p.id_site
   AND    create_date > p.create_date
   );
```

The logic, in plain English:

*Delete rows with a given `label` where a row with the same `label` and `id_site` but later `create_date` exists.*

This keeps the row with the latest date per set of peers (deleting 0-n duplicates).

**If** there can be duplicates with identical `create_date`:

```
DELETE FROM pages p
WHERE  label = '2018-12-15'
AND    EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM page
   WHERE  label       =  p.label
   AND    id_site     =  p.id_site
   AND    (create_date, id_page) > (p.create_date, p.id_page) --!
   );
```

*... from ties on `create_date` keep the row with the greater `id_page`.*

Note the ***row value comparison***! See, with explanation:

- [SQL syntax term for 'WHERE (col1, col2) < (val1, val2)'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32981903/sql-syntax-term-for-where-col1-col2-val1-val2/32982895#32982895)

Since `id_page` is the PK (as  revealed in a comment), this is unambiguous. If in doubt, the *second query* is the safe bet, only slightly slower.

To make this *fast*, an **index** on `(label, id_site)` would be perfect - with index expressions in this order. (Might not pay to create it for a one-time operation.)

#### Fast without index

```
DELETE FROM pages p
USING (
   SELECT id_page
        , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY id_site
                             ORDER BY create_date DESC, id_page DESC) AS rn
   FROM   pages
   WHERE  label = '2018-12-15'
   ) del
WHERE  p.id_page = del.id_page 
AND    del.rn > 1;
```

Similar to McNets query, but breaking possible ties on `create_date` like the 2nd query above.

Comment: I'd never thought of doing it like this but the query seems to run for much longer than using a windowing function. Is this related to creating the cross table first?

Comment: @CharlieClark: This query needs an index to be fast (typically faster than alternatives). I added details above. Else, a window function (or similar approach - there are many possible variants) will be faster. This query is short and clear in any case, performance may be of low importance for a one-time operation.

Comment: Thanks for the additional information and the example with `USING`. This is, hopefully, a once off task and I was pleasantly surprised by the speed of the windowing approach. Took me a while to work my way through it but I now understand the approach much better than before.

Comment: @CharlieClark: Consider the update for the 2nd query with row value comparison.